# Showing modal window causes unexpected issue

Tags: html, css

I have the following css:

```
html, body {background:#ebeced;min-height:100%;font-family:Helvetica}
body {overflow-y:scroll; cursor:default;}
```

And I add the `.fixed` class dynamically to the `body` when I open a modal window so that scrolling can't take place.

```
.fixed #container-wrapper {position:fixed;left:0;width:100%;}
```

I also have a fixed nav bar and then the content. The content is inside `container-wrapper`:

```
<body>
  <nav></nav>

  <div id="container-wrapper">
    <!-- all website content -->
  </div>
</body>
```

**Problem**

If I have scrolled down through the content at all and then open the modal, the content jumps right back to the top. I thought this may be an issue with `event.preventDefault` but I know now that it isn't to do with this. It's connected to the adding of the  `.fixed` class that causes the issue.

**JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/w9w9hthy/1/ - scroll down to the button and click the button. This will add a .fixed class and the content will "reset" to the top. How can I stop this "reset" effect?

Comment: Please provide more code / a demo to help with this. We have no code here the reflects the modal.

Comment: Added the css for the modal if it helps at all.

Comment: Set up a demo, or don't expect much help: the problem sounds quite specific.

Comment: Sorry - been away from the computer. Added a fiddle using jQuery (not Angular) but the effect is the same.

Comment: Remove #content height in the fiddler

Comment: Freezing scrollable page content is a bit more complicated due to page jumping issues and such, I wrote 2 functions for a project that work quite well but don't have code for horizontal scrollbar page jumping since taht seemed unnecesary in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `container-wrapper` `fixed` you can stop scrolling from happening by making the `body` `overflow: hidden` and removing it when you want scrolling to continue.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w9w9hthy/2/

```
.fixed {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thats true but I was avoiding using anything but css to solve this since javascript/jquery was not listed in the tags above.

Comment: Adding the class itself is already requiring js and the example code posted in the jsfiddle link uses jQuery which is why I posted a jQuery solution that changes CSS values on page freeze/unfreeze.

Comment: I understand but I was simply following the tags they used and the jsfiddle they provided. I hope your answer provides the person with everything they need. =]

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/w9w9hthy/5/

From my jQuery popup project: https://github.com/seahorsepip/jPopup

```
//Freeze page content scrolling
function freeze() {
        if($("html").css("position") != "fixed") {
            var top = $("html").scrollTop() ? $("html").scrollTop() : $("body").scrollTop();
            if(window.innerWidth > $("html").width()) {
                $("html").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
            }
            $("html").css({"width": "100%", "height": "100%", "position": "fixed", "top": -top});
        }
}
//Unfreeze page content scrolling
function unfreeze() {
        if($("html").css("position") == "fixed") {
            $("html").css("position", "static");
            $("html, body").scrollTop(-parseInt($("html").css("top")));
            $("html").css({"position": "", "width": "", "height": "", "top": "", "overflow-y": ""});
        }
}
```

This code takes, width, height, scrollbar and pagejump issues into consideration.

Possible issues resolved with above code:

- width, when setting position fixed the html element width can be smaller then 100%
- height, same as above
- scrollbar, when setting position fixed the page content no longer has a scrollbar even when it had a scrollbar before resulting in a horizontal pagejump
- pagejump, when setting position fixed the page scrollTop is no longer effective resulting in a vertical pagejump

If anyone has any improvements to above page freeze/unfreeze code let me know so I can add those improvements to my project.

Edit:

Just tested above code on some random pages and found some issues on some sites due to the use of body or html as main scroll content, I resolved those issues in above code and will push them to the github project.